# Polymorphism with smart pointers using templates

Tags: c++, sfml, smart-pointers

I'm having trouble putting a shared_ptr of sf::Text, sf::Sprite and sf::Text into an array of shared_ptr
sf::Drawable is the mother class of all the above and is abstract
Here's the game engine function:

GameEngine.h

```
template<class T>
    void add(std::shared_ptr<T> actor);
```

GameEngine.cpp

```
template<>
void GameEngine::add<sf::Drawable>(std::shared_ptr<sf::Drawable> actor)
{
    drawables.insert(actor);
}
```

Rendering.cpp

```
void Rendering::addDrawable(std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite> sprite, sf::Vector2i texture_rect, const char* texture_name)
{
    sf::Texture* _texture = engine.lock()->getGameData().getTexture(texture_name);
    if (_texture) {
        sprite->setTexture(*_texture);
        sprite->setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, texture_rect.x, texture_rect.y));
        //What do i have to put in the below function?
        engine.lock()->add(sprite);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error in VS 2015:

```
1>Rendering.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: void __thiscall GameEngine::add<class sf::Sprite>(class std::shared_ptr<class sf::Sprite>)" (??$add@VSprite@sf@@@GameEngine@@QAEXV?$shared_ptr@VSprite@sf@@@std@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: void __thiscall Rendering::addDrawable(class std::shared_ptr<class sf::Sprite>,class sf::Vector2<int>,char const *)" (?addDrawable@Rendering@@QAEXV?$shared_ptr@VSprite@sf@@@std@@V?$Vector2@H@sf@@PBD@Z)
1>Rendering.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: void __thiscall GameEngine::add<class sf::Shape>(class std::shared_ptr<class sf::Shape>)" (??$add@VShape@sf@@@GameEngine@@QAEXV?$shared_ptr@VShape@sf@@@std@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: void __thiscall Rendering::addDrawable(class std::shared_ptr<class sf::Shape>,char const *)" (?addDrawable@Rendering@@QAEXV?$shared_ptr@VShape@sf@@@std@@PBD@Z)
1>Rendering.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: void __thiscall GameEngine::add<class sf::Text>(class std::shared_ptr<class sf::Text>)" (??$add@VText@sf@@@GameEngine@@QAEXV?$shared_ptr@VText@sf@@@std@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: void __thiscall Rendering::addDrawable(class std::shared_ptr<class sf::Text>,char const *,char const *,class sf::Color)" (?addDrawable@Rendering@@QAEXV?$shared_ptr@VText@sf@@@std@@PBD1VColor@sf@@@Z)
```

Is there a way to put a shared pointer of a subclass into an array of shared pointers of its mother class?

EDIT:
An answer said that:

> Just because Sprite is a subclass of Drawable, does not mean that
>   `shared_ptr<Sprite>` is a subclass of `shared_ptr<Drawable>`.

Then why can i do this?

```
class A{};

class B : public A {};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> ar;
    ar.push_back(std::make_shared<B>());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where is the implementation of add()? it cannot find the definition of add()

Comment: Copied the wrong one, sorry, edited

Comment: i dont think this will even work because your template parameter is not match with the one that is declared, and you should define the template functions in the header file not in cpp

Comment: It works fine with other specialization and declaring it in the header or the cpp doesn't change anything

Comment: And its clearly written that the object i'm sending is a subobject of sf::Drawable

Comment: To answer you second question, it works because there is *no* template function type deduction going on.

Comment: Even though `shared_ptr<Sprite>` is not a subclass of `shared_ptr<Drawable>`, they are implicitly convertable. I've updated my answer to make that clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because `Sprite` is a subclass of `Drawable`, does not mean that `shared_ptr<Sprite>` is a subclass of `shared_ptr<Drawable>`.

When the compiler sees this:

```
engine.lock()->add(sprite);
```

it looks for a member function `add(shared_ptr<sf::Sprite>)` following the [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) rules.

Even though `shared_ptr<Sprite>` is not a subclass of `shared_ptr<Drawable>`, there is an implicit conversion available, so it would be a candidate.

However this:

```
template<class T>
    void add(std::shared_ptr<T> actor);
```

provides a **declaration** of the function for any type, but no **definition**. Therefore it provides an exact match and will be chosen by the compiler. That is why you get linker errors.

One way to solve this is to use [std::static_pointer_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast), like this:

```
engine.lock()->add(std::static_pointer_cast<Drawable>(sprite));
```

I would also reconsider if/why you need the template above - I can't see what purpose that is serving, other than to give you link time errors instead of compile time errors.